# How to pass the data from one cell to another view?

Tags: json, parsing, ios4, uitableview

I have created an application which loads data into UITableview by JSON parsing. Now when the user clicks on a cell, the user will be navigated to another view where the user can get the more details of the previous cell. I am able to pass the labels and all other things, but i am not able to pass the image from the previous cell. Can anyone please help me? thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableView has an underlying datasource, and a delegate

When you click the cell, it trigger the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method, which tells you the index of the cell that was clicked.

Use this to get the relevant information from your underlying datasource, and pass this over to the next view (as you already do with the label text etc.)

A high level example - you have an NSArray of a class, that has the image name, and image link. So, when the user clicks the cell at index 5, you get the object at index 5 in your array, and pass that information to the ViewController that you are about to push to the NavigationController.

In your case, you have to get that information from your JSON based on the index that was clicked. Or convert your JSON into an intermediary object.

Hope this helps.

---

```
UIImage *myImage = ...; // You have the UIImage.
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
controller.imageToDisplay = myImage; //declare public property.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
[controller release];
```

Comment: i agree with whatever u wrote n i too have done that already. the labels and other things are passed successfully but the problem is with passing the image.i took an array of strings for all the tags. now since image is not a string, so how to pass that??

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have the image in memory as a UIImage? Then you can just have a public property on your Viewcontroller that accepts UIImage *, and then on ViewWillAppear, display that UIImage. Otherwise, could you pass a url/path to the image itself and the UIImage can be loaded from there?

Comment: i have taken UIImageview from the library. now there is a tag in url as <image>. i get that image in the table view by JSON parsing but i am not able to pass it to another view. i am able to pass labels to another view form the table cell, but not able to pass the image.

Comment: You've ... completely lost me. You may need to elaborate on your question: JSON sample, code samples etc. and some guru might be able to assist you .